# The Close button in Custom button is not working in salesforce classic

Tags: custom-button, salesforce-classic

I have a  Custom Button in the Opportunity Detail Page called Submit Eval/Trial Request.
[image]
When i click on it a flow is executed.
[image]
but when i click the close button it doesn't close.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a URL button here. I am assuming that this close button is the finish button. When we use the URL button, then on clicking on finish, the flow will run again by default.

**There is the following solution to this problem -**

> - You can define **retURL** in your URL to redirect. [Reference](https://salesforce-flowsome.com/how-to-redirect-users-returl/)
> - You can create an action button and use flow in that action instead of the URL button.
> - If you have a specific requirement to use the URL button only,    then you can override the button behavior with the LWC component and
>   define your logic in LWC to navigate to your desired target.
> - You can refer to this document if you want to override with the LWC -
>   [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation)

Comment: Can you check this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396411/i-have-a-table-where-when-i-click-on-add-more-transactions-another-row-is-displa     @Gaurav_Suthar